# Find two non-empty languages whose concatenation is equal to another language

Tags: formal-languages

Let $L=\{a,b,ab,ba,bb,aab,bab,baab\}$. Find two Languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, both not equal to $\{\lambda\}$ over the Alphabet $\{a,b\}$ such that

$$L_1\cdot L_2=L.$$

The solution is $L_1=\{a,b,ba\}$, $L_2=\{\lambda, b, ab\}$.

Do you know a systematic way to always find the solution (or disprove the existence) for such a problem? I really can't see the process behind arriving to such a solution.

I tried to draw graphs with an "is-prefix-of" and "is-suffix-of" relation but that didn't get me to explain the solution.

Comment: This seems like more of a linguistics question, no?

Comment: @user1892304: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t give you an algorithm, but I can suggest how I might attack this particular problem. The words that begin with $b$ and are at least two letters long are $ba,bb,bab$, and $baab$, making up fully half of $L$, so I experiment with the possibility of putting $b$ in $L_1$ and $a,b,ab$, and $aab$ in $L_2$. Now

$$\{b\}\cdot\{a,b,ab,aab\}=\{ba,bb,bab,baab\}\;,$$

which at least doesn’t give me any unwanted words, and I still need to take care of $a,b,ab$, and $aab$. But these are exactly the words currently in $L_2$, so adding $\lambda$ to $L_1$ will do the job nicely: setting $L_1=\{\lambda,b\}$ and $L_2=\{a,b,ab,aab\}$ gives me a solution, albeit a different one from the one that you have.

Answer (score 2):

We want to find a list of prefixes and suffixes that form the words in $L$. We traverse the words in $L$ from left to right and add letters to $L_1$ and $L_2$ as needed. $L_1$ and $L_2$ start as empty sets.

Starting with $a$ I can form this as $a\lambda$ so I add $a$ to $L_1$ and $\lambda$ to $L_2$. Next, I want to get $b$ so I have two choices:

$1.$ I can add $b$ to $L_1$ and since I already have $\lambda$ in $L_2$ I get $b\lambda=b$ in $L$

$2.$ I can add $\lambda$ to $L_1$ and $b$ to $L_2$. The problem with this approach is that I now have $\lambda$ in both $L_1$ and $L_2$ but I don't have $\lambda\lambda=\lambda$ in $L$. Therefore, I must go with option $1$

So far I have $L_1=\{a, b\}$ and $L_2=\{\lambda\}$

I want $ab$ so I add $b$ to $L_2$ to get $L_1=\{a, b\}$ and $L_2=\{\lambda, b\}$

Now I want $ba$ and since I already have $b$ in $L_1$ it is tempting to just add $a$ to $L_2$. The problem with that is we would need $aa$ in $L$ which is not the case so we add $ba$ to $L_1$ to get $L_1=\{a, b, ba\}$ and $L_2=\{\lambda, b\}$.

So far, $L_1\cdot L_2=\{a, b, ba, ab, bb, bab\}$

I am missing $aab$ and $baab$ so I add $ab$ to $L_2$ to arrive at the final answer of $L_1=\{a, b, ba\}$ and $L_2=\{\lambda, b, ab\}$.

Comment: I can see somekind of an algorighm in your approach. It involves examining all words in canonical order and extending L1 and L2 such that the current word can be generated and meanwhile checking that no word other than the ones needed can be produced. - I'm not sure yet whether this method is guaranteed to lead to a solution if there is one. Maybe one might get stuck with this approach.

Comment: @ndrizza Yes. This does not guarantee a unique solution nor does this tell if no solution exists. It is simply how I would go about trying to solve this problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether that may always lead to a solution if there is one or whether it might get stuck even if there is one. I have to think about it.

Comment: @ndrizza  If your language is finite as in this case you should always be able to find a solution if one exists.